# .NET Bitmap Object

Tags: .net, image

I have stored an image as a BLOB (Varbinary(max)) in a database.  I encoded the image as a .NET Bitmap TIFF.  When displaying the image on the page, I am able to set the content type as JPEG, GIF etc and the image always appears correctly on the web page.  I would expect the image only to appear correctly if I set the content type as TIFF (as it was encoded as TIF).  I am using the Bitmap class.  Am I missing something?

Here is some code:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Img FROM dbImage where id = 1
                dr = objCmd.ExecuteReader
                dr.Read()

                screenshot = CType(dr("screenshot"), Byte())
                Response.ContentType = "image/tiff"
                Response.BinaryWrite(screenshot)
                Response.Flush()
                Response.End()
```

The BLOB image was encoded as a TIFF.  However, when extracting the image it will display in JPG and GIF.  For example, if I changed response.contenttype to "image/jpg", then it still displays.  The question is: why does it still display? I don't have a lot of experience with image processing.

Comment: Are you trying to re-encode the image by setting the Content-Type header? Or just wondering why setting it doesn't break your browser?

Comment: @Boo, thanks.  Yes, I am setting the Content Type and then using BinaryWrite to display the image (for testing only - the live system will have an ASHX Image Handler).

Comment: So what question that I asked does your "Yes" refer to, if any?

Comment: @boo, thanks. It does not seem what I set the content type to ie jpg, png etc, the image always displays. It does not break the browser.

Comment: And what exacly is the question then?  Do you want it to break?

Comment: @Boo, I have added some code.  Does this help to answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it still displays is because modern browsers ignore the content-type header for images (based on observation and testing, not on documentation).  The first few bytes of nearly every image will tell you what format it is in - I assume browsers (and the graphics libraries they use) look to these bytes (just as .NET does) instead of relying on the content-type header.

The web server is NOT re-encoding the image

Comment: thanks.  One more thing before I close this question.  I thought that TIFF images would not display in web browsers (I am using IE8 and Windows 7).  However, the TIFF images I have stored in the database all display perfectly in IE8 and Firefox.  Another user said that their tests have proven that sometimes a TIFF image will appear and sometimes they will not.  Is this the case?

Comment: I haven't tried to display a TIFF in a browser since IE7 (eg. too long ago for me to remember the outcome of those investigations).  Convention on the web says you limit the amount of data your users have to download.  Its cheaper for them and significantly cheaper for you.  So stuck to Jpg, Png, and in the very rare case Gif.